# How to display message when user disconnects from chat room in socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am working on a project in which there is a chat room. The messaging and the joining message is working fine but I don't know how to display a message when someone disconnects. I don't have much knowledge about socket.io as you will see in the code below.

(Edit)

Server Code(Express/Node)

```
    io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
    io.emit('message', { name, message })
  })
  socket.on('join' , (name)=>{
    console.log(name);
    socket.broadcast.emit("join" , name.usnm.toUpperCase() + " just joined")
  })
  socket.on('pre_disconnect', (name) => {
    console.log(name);
    socket.broadcast.emit("pre_disconnect" , name.usnm.toUpperCase() + " just left")
  })
})
```

Client Code(React.js)

```
const socketRef = useRef()
useEffect(
    () => {
        socketRef.current = io.connect("http://localhost:4000")
        
        socketRef.current.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {
            setChat([ ...chat, { name, message } ])
        })
        socketRef.current.on("join", (usnm) => {
            setChat([ ...chat, {name:usnm} ])
        })
        socketRef.current.on("pre_disconnect", (usnm) => {
        setChat([ ...chat, {name:usnm} ])
    })
    },
    [ chat ]
)
useEffect(
    () => {
        let usnm = sessionStorage.getItem("User");
        socketRef.current.emit("join" ,{usnm});
        return () => {
      socketRef.current.emit("pre_disconnect" ,{usnm});
      socketRef.current.disconnect()
    }
    },
    [  ]
)
```

In the code above the `pre_disconnect` doesn't do anything. Code works the same with or without it.

Comment: Against each socket id, are you maintaining the list of all the connected users on the server? Or is it just on the client-side?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the server app, define a `pre_disconnect` event which will be similar to the `join` event.

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', ({ name, message }) => {
    io.emit('message', { name, message })
  })
  socket.on('join', (name) => {
    console.log(name);
    socket.broadcast.emit("join" , name.usnm.toUpperCase() + " just joined")
  })
  // Fire this before disconnecting the socket
  socket.on('pre_disconnect', (name) => {
    console.log(name);
    socket.broadcast.emit("pre_disconnect" , name.usnm.toUpperCase() + " just left")
  })
})
```

2. In the first `useEffect` hook call, a new socket connection is made and closed everytime there is a `chat` state update. This means that number of messages in the current session will be generated by amount of socket connects/disconnects. [From React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

> The default behavior for effects is to fire the effect after every completed render. That way an effect is always recreated if one of its dependencies changes. However, this may be overkill in some cases, like the subscription example from the previous section. We don’t need to create a new subscription on every update, only if the source prop has changed. To implement this, pass a second argument to useEffect that is the array of values that the effect depends on.

Similarly, unless you explicitly need to create and close a new connection on every `chat` update, avoid it for performance reasons.

3. In the react app, fire `pre_disconnect` event with `usnm`, before calling `socketRef.current.disconnect()` and add the appropriate handler similar to `join`.

```js
const socketRef = useRef()
useEffect(() => {
    // socketRef.current = io.connect("http://localhost:4000")
    if (socketRef.current) {
        // Add socketRef as dependency and check if socketRef.current exists then continue with listeners
        socketRef.current.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {
            setChat([...chat, { name, message }]);
        });
        socketRef.current.on("join", (usnm) => {
            setChat([...chat, { name: usnm }]);
        });

        // handler for disconnect message
        socketRef.current.on("pre_disconnect", (usnm) => {
            setChat([...chat, { name: usnm }]);
        });
    }
    // return () => socketRef.current.disconnect()
}, [chat, socketRef]);
useEffect(
    () => {
        // Here, creates a socket connection only when component renders the first time. Similar to componentDidMount() in class components
        socketRef.current = io.connect("http://localhost:4000")
        let usnm = sessionStorage.getItem("User");
        socketRef.current.emit("join" ,{usnm});

        // Disconnect the socket when component is to be unmounted from DOM. Similar to componentWillUnmount() in class components
        return () => {
          socketRef.current.emit("pre_disconnect" ,{usnm});
          socketRef.current.disconnect()
        }
    },
    [  ]
)
```

Edit:

You were getting that error because `socketRef` was not initialized. I have added `socketRef` as a dependency and wrapped the code inside an `if` condition. Please check the changes.

Comment: Sir I have made the changes you suggested in my code, but still it is not working, Actually it didn't made any impact on the output. I have edited the code in the question, kindly check it. Also in your code you have commented the `io.connect` part in the upper `useEffect`, so it was throwing error so I didn't followed that step.

Comment: Check the edits. I think the error was because "socketRef.current" was accessed before initialization.